# How to compare two servers for performance tuning?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, aws

I have two web servers (AWS instances) with exact same configuration of apache and php-fpm.

Both of them are behind a load-balancer. One server is able to serve more request as compared to the other by 30%. System Load is the same, no other processes running.

The performant server is Debian, the slower server is Ubuntu.
We did some tuning few months back but now I cant recall what we actually did.

What could be the first few usual suspects that I should check for on both these servers?

PS:
These instances are on AWS.
The better performing instance was manually created and the other instance is created automatically via Auto Scaling Group.
The Load balancing algorithm is Least outstanding requests.

Comment: are these servers *actually* server marchines, or are they VMs on a shared-premise cloud computing platform?

Comment: These are AWS instances.

Comment: that seems to be very important. Added it to the question. How is your load balancing done? Who decides, and based on what, which requests go to which instance? Did you provision both from the same image at the same time, or did one come later?

Comment: @MarcusMüller added more information.